# Powers in AC circuit using complex numbers

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, ac

[image: Schematic with text]

I have calculated the current flowing through the entire circuit, but if i use CDR (2 < 36.87 x (60 < 90 / 60 < 90 + 20 <- 90) to calculate the current being divided to the resistor and inductor, my answer is 2 amp angled 55.305 through the capacitor, which is completely different than the actual answer, been stuck on this for a while, any help is appreciated.

I don't understand why the current through inductor can't be calculated with the method I did, what concept am I missing?

Comment: I tried to edit this into the question, but the picture disappeared. \$ 2 \angle 36.87 \frac{60 \angle 90}{60 \angle 90 + 20 \angle -90} \$

Comment: Can you leave an attempt at an answer and show your work?

Comment: Are you calculating power dissipated, or reactive power (VARs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current Divider Rule:

\$ I_X = \frac{Z_T}{Z_X + Z_T} I_T  \$

\$ Z_T = Z_1 || Z_2 || Z_n , excluding \:R_X\$

Capacitor current:

\$ 2 \angle 36.87 \frac{60 \angle 90}{60 \angle 90 + 20 \angle -90} = 2 \angle 36.87 \frac{60 \angle 90}{40 \angle 90} = 2 \angle 36.87 * 1.5  = 3 \angle 36.87 \$

Inductor current:

\$ 2 \angle 36.87 \frac{20 \angle 90}{60 \angle 90 + 20 \angle -90} = 2 \angle 36.87 \frac{20 \angle -90}{40 \angle 90} = 2 \angle 36.87 * 0.5 \angle{-180} = 1 \angle{-143.13} \$

Power dissipated in perfect capacitors and inductors is zero.

Reactive power for an inductor:

\$ VAR = I^2 X_L = 1^2 * 60 = 60 \; VAR \$

Reactive power for a capacitor:

\$ VAR = - I^2 X_C = 3^2 * 20 = -180 \; VAR \$

Note that the angle of the current (relative to the source) is not used, the component doesn't care.

If this isn't what your issues are, edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, i get the question now and can solve it and similar questions, thanks a lott

Comment: the error was caused by the calculator giving different answers if i used the entire equation as input rather than solving it in steps like you did

Comment: Note that I assumed that the 100 V source was RMS, this is what I believe that a Power Engineer would assume. *Jan* assumed that it was peak. If you use the CircuitLab simulator, it also assumes that it is peak. This is why our power numbers differ by a factor of 2. @Aura, if you don't know which convention is used in your class, ask your professor.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's first find all the voltages and currents that we need. So, we start with the magnitude of the input current:

$$\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|=\left|\frac{\displaystyle\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}}{\displaystyle\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}}\right|=\frac{\displaystyle\left|100\right|}{\displaystyle\left|40+\frac{\displaystyle60\text{j}\left(-20\text{j}\right)}{\displaystyle60\text{j}-20\text{j}}\right|}=\frac{\displaystyle100}{\displaystyle\left|40-30\text{j}\right|}=\frac{\displaystyle100}{\displaystyle\sqrt{40^2+30^2}}=2\space\text{A}\tag1$$

So, we know that the magnitude of the voltage across the resistor is given by:

$$\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{R}}\right|=\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|\text{R}=2\cdot40=80\space\text{V}\tag2$$

Now, we can use the current divider formula to find the magnitude of the current trough the capacitor and coil:

$$\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{L}}\right|=\frac{\displaystyle\left|-20\text{j}\right|}{\displaystyle\left|60\text{j}-20\text{j}\right|}\cdot\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|=\frac{\displaystyle20}{\displaystyle\left|40\text{j}\right|}\cdot2=\frac{\displaystyle20}{\displaystyle40}\cdot2=1\space\text{A}\tag3$$
$$\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{C}}\right|=\frac{\displaystyle\left|60\text{j}\right|}{\displaystyle\left|60\text{j}-20\text{j}\right|}\cdot\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|=\frac{\displaystyle60}{\displaystyle\left|40\text{j}\right|}\cdot2=\frac{\displaystyle60}{\displaystyle40}\cdot2=3\space\text{A}\tag4$$

So, the magnitude of the voltages across them is given by:

$$\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{L}}\right|=\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{L}}\right|\cdot\left|60\text{j}\right|=1\cdot60=60\space\text{V}\tag5$$
$$\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{C}}\right|=\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{C}}\right|\cdot\left|-20\text{j}\right|=3\cdot20=60\space\text{V}\tag6$$

Now, we can calculate \$\displaystyle\varphi\$ for all components:

- Source:
  $$\varphi_\text{source}=\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=\arg\left(40-30\text{j}\right)=\frac{\displaystyle3\pi}{\displaystyle2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle4}{\displaystyle3}\right)\tag7$$
- Resistor:
  $$\varphi_\text{R}=\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}}\right)=\arg\left(40\right)=0\tag8$$
- Coil:
  $$\varphi_\text{L}=\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{L}}\right)=\arg\left(60\text{j}\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\pi}{\displaystyle2}\tag9$$
- Capacitor:
  $$\varphi_\text{C}=\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{C}}\right)=\arg\left(-20\text{j}\right)=\frac{\displaystyle3\pi}{\displaystyle2}\tag{10}$$

Now, we can find all the powers:

- Source:
  $$
  \begin{alignat*}{1}
  \text{P}_\text{source}&=\text{V}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{source}}\text{I}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{source}}\cos\left(\varphi_\text{source}\right)\\
  \\
  &=\frac{100}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\cos\left(\frac{\displaystyle3\pi}{\displaystyle2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle4}{\displaystyle3}\right)\right)\\
  \\
  &=80\space\text{W}
  \end{alignat*}\tag{11}
  $$
  $$
  \begin{alignat*}{1}
  \text{Q}_\text{source}&=\text{V}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{source}}\text{I}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{source}}\sin\left(\varphi_\text{source}\right)\\
  \\
  &=\frac{100}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\displaystyle3\pi}{\displaystyle2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle4}{\displaystyle3}\right)\right)\\
  \\
  &=-60\space\text{VAR}
  \end{alignat*}\tag{12}
  $$
  $$
  \begin{alignat*}{1}
  \text{S}_\text{source}&=\text{V}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{source}}\text{I}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{source}}\\
  \\
  &=\frac{100}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\\
  \\
  &=100\space\text{VA}
  \end{alignat*}\tag{13}
  $$
- Resistor:
  $$
  \begin{alignat*}{1}
  \text{P}_\text{R}&=\text{V}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{R}}\text{I}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{R}}\cos\left(\varphi_\text{R}\right)\\
  \\
  &=\frac{80}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\cos\left(0\right)\\
  \\
  &=80\space\text{W}
  \end{alignat*}\tag{14}
  $$
  $$
  \begin{alignat*}{1}
  \text{Q}_\text{R}&=\text{V}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{R}}\text{I}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{R}}\sin\left(\varphi_\text{R}\right)\\
  \\
  &=\frac{80}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\sin\left(0\right)\\
  \\
  &=0\space\text{VAR}
  \end{alignat*}\tag{15}
  $$
  $$
  \begin{alignat*}{1}
  \text{S}_\text{R}&=\text{V}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{R}}\text{I}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{R}}\\
  \\
  &=\frac{80}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\\
  \\
  &=80\space\text{VA}
  \end{alignat*}\tag{16}
  $$
- Coil:
  $$
  \begin{alignat*}{1}
  \text{P}_\text{L}&=\text{V}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{L}}\text{I}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{L}}\cos\left(\varphi_\text{L}\right)\\
  \\
  &=\frac{60}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
  \\
  &=0\space\text{W}
  \end{alignat*}\tag{17}
  $$
  $$
  \begin{alignat*}{1}
  \text{Q}_\text{L}&=\text{V}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{L}}\text{I}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{L}}\sin\left(\varphi_\text{L}\right)\\
  \\
  &=\frac{60}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
  \\
  &=30\space\text{VAR}
  \end{alignat*}\tag{18}
  $$
  $$
  \begin{alignat*}{1}
  \text{S}_\text{L}&=\text{V}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{L}}\text{I}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{L}}\\
  \\
  &=\frac{60}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
  \\
  &=30\space\text{VA}
  \end{alignat*}\tag{19}
  $$
- Capacitor:
  $$
  \begin{alignat*}{1}
  \text{P}_\text{C}&=\text{V}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{C}}\text{I}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{C}}\cos\left(\varphi_\text{C}\right)\\
  \\
  &=\frac{60}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\\
  \\
  &=0\space\text{W}
  \end{alignat*}\tag{20}
  $$
  $$
  \begin{alignat*}{1}
  \text{Q}_\text{C}&=\text{V}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{C}}\text{I}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{C}}\sin\left(\varphi_\text{C}\right)\\
  \\
  &=\frac{60}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\\
  \\
  &=-90\space\text{VAR}
  \end{alignat*}\tag{21}
  $$
  $$
  \begin{alignat*}{1}
  \text{S}_\text{C}&=\text{V}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{C}}\text{I}_{\text{RMS}\space|\space\text{C}}\\
  \\
  &=\frac{60}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\\
  \\
  &=90\space\text{VA}
  \end{alignat*}\tag{22}
  $$

Comment: Note that I assumed that the 100 V source was RMS, this is what I believe that a Power Engineer would assume. You assumed that it was peak. If you use the CircuitLab simulator, it also assumes that it is peak. This is why our power numbers differ by a factor of 2. @Aura, if you don't know which convention is used in your class, ask your professor.